# Posting Retrofit to Rest server in Android

Tags: php, android, json, retrofit

As part of a group university project, we're using a PHP rest server to send data to an Oracle server. So far, all of the get methods work fine, but I'm having trouble understanding how to post data, as it's not working.

This is the PHP

```
    $app->post('/room', function () use ($app) {
    $request = $app->getInstance()->request();
    $room = json_decode($request->getBody(), true);
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO rooms VALUES(null, :room_pcm, :property_id)';
    $query = oci_parse(getConnection(), $sql);
    $room_pcm = $room['ROOM_PCM'];
    $property_id = $room['PROPERTY_ID'];
    oci_bind_by_name($query, ':room_pcm', $room_pcm);
    oci_bind_by_name($query, ':property_id', $property_id);
    oci_execute($query);
});
```

But I can't for the life of me get this to work in Android.

This is the method I'm using to post data:

```
    @FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/room")
Room postRoom(Integer roomId, Double pcm, Integer propID);
```

And from the activity

```
    public void insertARoom(){
    RestService.INSTANCE.getService().postRoom(200, 50.0, 103);
}
```

The error it is saying is it needs a retrofit annotation on parameter 1.
I've also tried using a callback of type Property but this still gave me problems.

Ideally, the first parameter should be null as it's a primary key, how could I do this?

Thanks
Omar

EDIT:

Logcat output, and yet the Internet permission is there.

```
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913): Process: prcsc.android, PID: 1913
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913): retrofit.RetrofitError: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:425)
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:282)
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at $Proxy0.postRoom(Native Method)
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at prcsc.android.fragment.PropertyDetailFragment$3.onClick(PropertyDetailFragment.java:170)
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:163)
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:506)
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:168)
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:227)
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.isReadable(Connection.java:214)
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:108)
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.prepareRequest(UrlConnectionClient.java:89)
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.execute(UrlConnectionClient.java:48)
03-31 06:15:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:357)
```

The rest adapter is using GSON

```
    public Rest getService() {
    if (RestService.service == null) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Image.class,
                new ImageDeserialiser()).registerTypeAdapter(CountInteger.class, new CountDeserialiser()).create();
        RestService.service = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(RestService.URL)
                .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson)).build()
                .create(Rest.class);
    }
    return RestService.service;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apologies for the late reply to this.

I solved it. It was mainly my lack of understanding of how Retrofit and Slim worked.

This is how it should have been:

```
    @POST("/room")
    void postRoom(@Body Room room, Callback<Integer> rc);
```

All I had to do from the Android app was pass it a parameter of type Room, and on the PHP side it used JSON to decode the body and fetch the result.

Many thanks again,

Omar

Comment: Sorry, would you mind putting the piece of PHP code where you pick the Room class? @Omar.Ebrahim

Answer (score 1):

In order to send your data, you have to "prefix" each parameter with a `@Field` annotation like this:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/room")
Room postRoom(@Field("roomId") Integer roomId, @Field("pcm") Double pcm, @Field("propID") Integer propID);
```

Comment: It's eliminated the callback error but it now has a problem with opening a socket to send the data. Not sure why.

Comment: How to how create your `RestAdapter`? Did you add the `INTERNET` permission within your `AndroidManifest.xml`? Also, can you please post the full logcat error stack for this error, it's really difficult to help you with such little information. Thanks.

Comment: Edited main post with logcat output

Comment: You got a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` because you are trying to do a network operation within the UI thread which it not allowed from Android 3.0 and above. Even if you use retrofit, it doesn't mean that the request will run on another thread. You have to wrap that into a [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or a [`AsyncTaskLoader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html)

Comment: No you should never wrap it in AsyncTask. You must provide a callback function and it will be run in another thread asynchronously.