# How get retrofit data with PHP

Tags: php, android, retrofit2

Good Morning,

I would like to know how to collect the data sent from my application Retrofit.

I have this code to send some atributes:

```
@POST("config/")
Call<RegisterResponse> sendRegID(@Body RegisterRequest registerRequest);
```

How I can get each of the attributes of the class RegisterRequest?I need PHP code

Thanks

**EDIT**

I just need to know what name could pick up the JSON sent by Retrofit, for example:

```
$_POST['JSON']
```

Later to be able to do this:

```
$cadena = json_decode($_POST['JSON'])
```

I have seen in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22758382/posting-retrofit-to-rest-server-in-android) a way to do this, but `$app` not know as initialized.

Once achieved the JSON, you need to extract each key-value inside the JSON, but that if I have more or less in mind how to do it

Comment: I edited the question @Vuldo , if you understand better what I ask

Comment: thank you very much for the negative votes to one who has given (irony), I know PHP, although I have 5 years without using them, and to resume it did not know how to relate an application on Android with PHP, but of course here is that there are people so so clever that does not help or suggest ideas or ways to investigate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is just a post of one singular registerRequest in the body, I would think you just need to construct your model object on the PHP side with the same attributes used in Android...so

```
$data = json_decode($_POST);
```

or

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

then

```
$someAttr = $data["someAttr"]
```

Comment: My object in Android has 3 parameters, but with `$data=json_decode ['$_ POST']` the object sent from the mobile App collects, I really facilitates the following operations.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you very much really @snkashis , because there are people who do not help and only criticize or give negative feedback

Comment: no problem at all.